# Collection View is faulty when on ipad2?

Tags: swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a 3 collection views on a page. However when I run it on ipad two it doubles up like in the image below:

[This is the faulty view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ARVG.png)

This is what it should look like and it does on iphone:

[This is what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRxJd.png)

I have a feeling it has something to do with the constraints, but the code for the delegate is this:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == prodCollectionView {
         //print("There are \(prodImage.count) prodImage Items")
        return prodImage.count
    }
    else if collectionView == revenueCollectionView {
        //print("There are \(revImage.count) revImage items")
        return revImage.count
    }
    else{
        //print("There are \(accImage.count) accImage items")
        return accImage.count
    }

}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let kWhateverHeightYouWant: CGFloat = 100
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, kWhateverHeightYouWant)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == prodCollectionView {
        //print("collectionViewOne")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("productCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        checkBegin[0] = indexPath.item
        cell.images = self.prodImage[indexPath.item]
        //collectionView.bounds = CGRect(x: <#T##CGFloat#>, y: <#T##CGFloat#>, width: <#T##CGFloat#>, height: <#T##CGFloat#>))
        return cell
    }
    else if collectionView == revenueCollectionView{
        //print("CollectionViewTwo")
        //print(indexPath.item)
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("revCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! revenueImageCollectionViewCell
        checkBegin[1] = indexPath.item

        cell.images = self.revImage[indexPath.item]
                    return cell
    }
    else {
       // print("CollectioNVieWThree")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("accCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AccessImageCollectionViewCell
        checkBegin[2] = indexPath.item
        cell.images = self.accImage[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: You linked the same image twice; impossible to tell exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Is there any more information I could add to help figure out whats wrong?

Comment: Yes, explain exactly what is the problem. What do mean by "However when I run it on ipad two **it doubles up** like in the image below:"?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I attached the wrong image, you'll find the the image in the first link, which will show you the issue